# What is the proper mime-type on a link rel pingback (WordPress)?

Tags: wordpress, pingback

This question applies to WordPress, but maybe someone knows if it applies universally?

Is there a proper mime-type (type attribute) for this... ?

```
<link rel="pingback" type="WHICH-TYPE/HERE?" href="http://www.example.com/xmlrpc.php" />
```

Something tells me it may be `text/xml`, but I'd rather not guess if someone knows the right answer.

**EDIT:**

I am [reading here](http://www.hixie.ch/specs/pingback/pingback-1.0) that including a `link rel pingback` in your `<head>` is discouraged...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the specs ( http://www.hixie.ch/specs/pingback/pingback ), you don't need to specify a type attribute.

Presumably because it doesn't send any content.

Comment: I understand you don't NEED to specify a type, just wondering what the proper type is, if any. Maybe there is no "right" answer?